# Generic async try catch on base API - ASP NET CORE

Tags: api, asp.net-core, generics

I have created a generic try/catch method on base API on a net core 2.2 project,  and I am not sure about perfomance of this generic method. Is this a good way to do it?

This is on base api:

```
protected async Task<IActionResult> TryReturnOk<TReturn>(Func<Task<TReturn>> function)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await function();
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _fileLogger.LogError(ex.Message);
                _fileLogger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);

                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }
```

And it is used on post method in the api-s like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] LogViewModel log)
{
    return await TryReturnOk(() => _writeLogService.WriteLog(log));
}
```

Comment: You may want to also log `InnerException` if it's not null. That should be done in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cluttering up all your controllers, I would centralized logging to middleware like below.

`400 Bad Request` should be used when e.g. request model is not valid. When an exception is thrown, 500 is more appropriate.

```
public class LoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _fileLogger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger fileLogger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _fileLogger = fileLogger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _fileLogger.LogError(ex.Message);
            _fileLogger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}

public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LoggerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

In Startup#Configure

```
app.UseLoggerMiddleware()
```